# Label not positioned correctly in box-toolbar (Bootstrap 3.0 Theme)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, themes

I am working with a Bootstrap Theme in order to show a Box with a Header and a Title. In the box-header, I add a label to the box-toolbar, but it is not displayed correctly. Somehow it is moving above the box-header.

Relevant HTML Code:

```
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="container padded">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="box">
              <div class="box-header">
                <span class="title">Stammdaten</span>
                <ul class="box-toolbar">
                  <li><span class="label label-green">Kunde</span></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Can anyone help me to fix this issue? It is the same code that is also present in the Bootstrap Theme itself, but there it is showing up correctly. Thank you.

CSS:

```
.box .box-header .box-toolbar, .box .box-footer .box-toolbar {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   float: right;
   list-style: none;
}

.label-green {
   background: #6eb056;
   background-image:url('data:something...');
   background-size: 100%;
   background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #8cc079),    color-stop(100%, #6eb056));
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8cc079, #6eb056);
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8cc079, #6eb056);
   background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #8cc079, #6eb056);
   background-image: linear-gradient(top, #8cc079, #6eb056);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #f7f7f7, inset 0 1px 1px #80b96b;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #f7f7f7, inset 0 1px 1px #80b96b;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #f7f7f7, inset 0 1px 1px #80b96b;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your custom CSS (box-header,box-toolbar,label-green) too?

Comment: I added the custom CSS.